# how I can close a window of notepad++ properly without stop-process?

Tags: powershell

I want to close properly a window of notepad++ but it doesn't work.What is the solution please?

Here is my code:

```
$pathcoalaclient="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
    
     $process=Start-Process -FilePath  $pathcoalaclient -Verb RunAs -PassThru   
       Start-Sleep -s 5
        $process.CloseMainWindow()
```

Here is my output:

```
True
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "properly", as well as "doesn't work"?

Comment: The same code works just fine for notepad.

Comment: `(Get-Process -Name notepad).Kill()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Unfortunately, **the fact that [`.CloseMainWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process.CloseMainWindow) returns `$true` does *not* guarantee that the window *actually* closes and that the target process exits** - all it tells you whether the Windows message *requesting* closure was successfully *sent*.
- Indeed, **in your case the window does *not* close, because you've launched `Notpad++.exe` in an *elevated* session** ([`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)`-Verb RunAs`). Seemingly, presumably related to *permissions*, `.CloseMainWindow()` is then *not* effective.

  - However, ***if acceptable*, given the risk of *data loss* - you can fall back to

    [`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) in order to *kill*** (forcefully terminate) the process.

A working example:

```
# Note: I'm using Notepad.exe for simplicity here.
$pathcoalaclient = "Notepad.exe"
    
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $pathcoalaclient -Verb RunAs -PassThru   
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5


# Call .CloseMainWindow() but note that return value $true
# isn't a reliable indicator for whether the window actually closed.
# NOTE: If you KNOW that the process was created WITH ELEVATION
#       - as in this case - you can skip this call altogether.
$requestSuccessfullySent = $process.CloseMainWindow()

if ($requestSuccessfullySent) {
  # The process may or may not exit.
  # Wait a reasonable amount of time to see if it does.
  # Note: If the request to close couldn't even be sent - this could be 
  #       due to application hanging, currently showing a *modal* dialog, 
  #       or being in the process of / already having exited - 
  #       there is no strict need to wait, although you still may choose to, 
  #       in order to minimize the risk of data loss.
  $process | Wait-Process -Timeout 3 -ErrorAction Ignore    
}

# Take additional action, if the process did *not* exit.
if (-not $process.HasExited) {
  Write-Warning "The $($process.Name) process did not exit on its own within the timeout period."
  # !! IF it is acceptable,
  # !! you can *kill* the process now, but note that this can 
  # !! result in *data loss*
  Write-Warning "Killing the $($process.Name) process..."
  $process | Stop-Process -Force
}
```

Note that **[`Stop-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process) *unconditionally kills*,** i.e. it always terminates processes *forcefully*, risking data loss. Potentially offering *graceful* termination at least on an *opt-in* basis in the future (post-PowerShell 7.2) is the subject of [GitHub issue #13664](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13664#issuecomment-777935849).